# Dimensions of spaces over different fields

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, span

We view $\Bbb C_2 = \{{w \choose z}:w,z\in \Bbb C\}$ as a vector space over $\Bbb C$, $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb Q$. Let $x_1={i \choose 0}$, $x_2={\sqrt2 \choose \sqrt5}$, $x_3={0 \choose 1}$, $x_4={i\sqrt3 \choose \sqrt3}$, $x_5={1 \choose 3}\in C_2$. Determine $\dim_F(\operatorname{Span}_F\{x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5\})$ for $F=\Bbb C$, $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb Q$.

I largely need help on understanding the concept of the dimension space over different fields, and have provided an example to help.

Thanks.

EDIT: For $\Bbb C$, we can use the definition of dim$_F$(F$^n$)=n to deduce that the dimension is 2 (i think). Still struggling with $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Your way of using MathJax is bizarre.  I've cleaned it up. For example, I changed $\Bbb C$ 2 = $\{$ ${w \choose z}$:w,z$\in$ $\Bbb C$ $\}$ to $\Bbb C_2 = \{ {w\choose z}:w,z\in\Bbb C\}$. I also altered some notation, changing $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)$ to $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5\}$ since this apparently should be a set rather than a tuple. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thanks for that, still getting to learn the notation for MathJax.

Comment: @michaelhardy I even learned a thing - I've been using mathbb and braces for years; I had no idea that Bbb was a thing! How convenient